# Problem with drawing a clock with Direct2D

Tags: c++, c, winapi, directx, direct2d

I am trying to draw a clock with Direct2D.  The program correctly gets the current time, however the error is when Direct2D draws the clock, since it seems that the clock is out of date with the current time. To get the current time, use the `GetLocalTime()` function and then map the values to transform them to an angle, so that they can be drawn. How could I fix it?

```
...

renderTarget->BeginDraw();
renderTarget->Clear(ColorF(ColorF::Black));

GetLocalTime(&sysTime);

wstring text = L"Hour: " + to_wstring(sysTime.wHour)
    + L"\nMinute: " + to_wstring(sysTime.wMinute)
    + L"\nSecond: " + to_wstring(sysTime.wSecond);

brush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::White));
renderTarget->DrawTextW(text.c_str(), text.length(), textFormat, textRect, brush);

D2D1_POINT_2F centerPoint = Point2F(320, 240);
FLOAT hourAngle = map(sysTime.wHour%12, 0, 12, 0, 360);
FLOAT minuteAngle = map(sysTime.wMinute, 0, 60, 0, 360);
FLOAT secondAngle = map(sysTime.wSecond, 0, 60, 0, 360);

brush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::DeepPink));
renderTarget->DrawEllipse(D2D1::Ellipse(centerPoint, 150, 150), brush, 5);

renderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Rotation(secondAngle, centerPoint));
brush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::Blue));
renderTarget->DrawLine(centerPoint,Point2F(centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y + 150*0.9), brush, 10,lineStrokeStyle);

renderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Rotation(minuteAngle, centerPoint));
brush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::White));
renderTarget->DrawLine(centerPoint,Point2F(centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y + 150*0.7), brush, 10, lineStrokeStyle);

renderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Rotation(hourAngle, centerPoint));
brush->SetColor(ColorF(ColorF::GreenYellow));
renderTarget->DrawLine(centerPoint, Point2F(centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y + 150*0.5), brush, 10,lineStrokeStyle);

renderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Identity());

HRESULT hrErr = renderTarget->EndDraw();

if (hrErr != S_OK) {
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Direct2D Error", L"Direct2D Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    SafeRelease(&brush);
    SafeRelease(&renderTarget);
    SafeRelease(&factory);
}

...
```

Comment: What's map() do?

Comment: The map function linearly maps the time to an angle. I used this function to convert the hours, minutes and seconds to an angle of 0 ° to 360 °.

Comment: I used the formula that deals in this page: https: //rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#C.2B.2B

Comment: Without seeing your code for map() how are we supposed to know if that's where the problem is or not? Have you checked what angles it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `GetLocalTime` to get the current local date and time. The problem may be in mapping the time to an angle.

But these can be solved, because there are very detailed examples in MSDN.

Instead of calculating the coordinates for the lines, we can calculate the angle and then apply a rotation transform. The following code shows a function that draws one clock hand. The fAngle parameter gives the angle of the hand, in degrees.

```
void Scene::DrawClockHand(float fHandLength, float fAngle, float fStrokeWidth)
{
    m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(
        D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(fAngle, m_ellipse.point)
            );

    // endPoint defines one end of the hand.
    D2D_POINT_2F endPoint = D2D1::Point2F(
        m_ellipse.point.x,
        m_ellipse.point.y - (m_ellipse.radiusY * fHandLength)
        );

    // Draw a line from the center of the ellipse to endPoint.
    m_pRenderTarget->DrawLine(
        m_ellipse.point, endPoint, m_pStroke, fStrokeWidth);
}
```

This code draws a vertical line, starting from the center of the clock face and ending at the point endPoint. The line is rotated around the center of the ellipse by applying a rotation transform. The center point for the rotation is the center of ellipse that forms the clock face.

```
void Scene::RenderScene()
{
    m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::SkyBlue));

    m_pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(m_ellipse, m_pFill);
    m_pRenderTarget->DrawEllipse(m_ellipse, m_pStroke);

    // Draw hands
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetLocalTime(&time);

    // 60 minutes = 30 degrees, 1 minute = 0.5 degree
    const float fHourAngle = (360.0f / 12) * (time.wHour) + (time.wMinute * 0.5f);
    const float fMinuteAngle =(360.0f / 60) * (time.wMinute);

    DrawClockHand(0.6f,  fHourAngle,   6);
    DrawClockHand(0.85f, fMinuteAngle, 4);

    // Restore the identity transformation.
    m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform( D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity() );
}
```

Refer: [Drawing Clock Hands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/applying-transforms-in-direct2d#drawing-clock-hands)

Debug:

[image: 1]

The whole code sample:

- [Direct2D Clock Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/begin/LearnWin32/Direct2DClock)

Comment: I'm sorry, but an answer needs to answer the question. This is just your average *"Try this instead, it works"*, completely ignoring the question. A quality answer needs to explain, what the issue is, and how the proposed answer addresses it.